# Fading in / out my popup?

Tags: jquery, popup, jqmodal

I'm using jqModal and it does everything I want to, however I want to add a fade effect for showing and hiding the popup, it currently just shows and hides and I find it a bit too sudden. The problem is I have tried everything to get it to fade in but I am having no luck whatsoever.

Can you help me achieve this? Even if it's some kind of alternative solution :)

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
   $('.jqmWindow').jqm({ ajax:'people'});
   $('.jqmWindow').jqmShow();
});

$('.jqmWindow').on('click', '.close', function(){
   $('.jqmWindow').jqmHide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
var myFadeIn=function(hash){
    hash.w.fadeIn("2000");
};

var myFadeOut=function(hash){
    hash.w.fadeOut("2000",function(){
        hash.o.remove(); 
    });
};

$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('.jqmWindow').jqm({
        ajax:'people',
        onShow:myFadeIn,
        onHide:myFadeOut
    });
    $('.jqmWindow').jqmShow();
});

$('.jqmWindow').on('click', '.close', function(){
    $('.jqmWindow').jqmHide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realise I could have done it like that! :)